# Get the site permission list with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions

By clicking "Site Settings" > "Site Permission" I can get a list of permission setup for the site. I need to export the exact list with PowerShell to CSV. May I know how to do it?

By using

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://url"
$web.Permissions
```

I get a list very similar. However it is showing "BasePermissions" (e.g.  ViewListItems, AddListItems, EditListItems, DeleteListItems,
 OpenItems, ViewVersions, DeleteVersions, ManagePersonalViews,
  ViewFormPages, Open, ViewPages, CreateSSCSite, ManagePermiss
 ions, BrowseDirectories, BrowseUserInfo, UseClientIntegration).

It is not what I want. I want to show the permission level exactly same as GUI provide. (e.g. Full Control, Limited Access)

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one,

```
foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments) 
 { 
  if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($roleAssignment.Member.Xml)) 
   { 
    foreach($roleDefinBindings in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
    {
         Write-Output $roleAssignment.Member.Name
         Write-Output $roleDefinBindings.Name 
    } 

   } 
 } 
}
```

Check current member is SharePointGroup/SecurityGroup/User. [Reference](http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2016/11/20/Full-Permission-Report-PowerShell)

```
if($roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.SharePointGroup)
{
#SharePointGroup
}
if($roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.SecurityGroup)
{
#SecurityGroup
}
if($roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User)
{
#User
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very close to my need. I am looking for way to display "Group Type" (i.e. Domain Group, SharePoint Group, User)

Comment: @vishal-m-patil  The above does not serve the purpose, though it displays group and permission; it did not display the user for each group.

Comment: I tested "PrincipalType" is not a member of "$roleAssignment.Member".

Comment: try to load $roleAssignment & $roleAssignment.Member in context before using it. [look at this article](http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2016/11/20/Full-Permission-Report-PowerShell)

Comment: Is it supported in SP2010? it returns "New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]"

Answer (score 2):

You can use it, you must modify the $ site variable to point to your site collection.

```
Syntax: <script name>.ps1 | out-file c:\permissions.txt
```

Here is [script](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/08/powershell-script-to-display-unique-permissions-for-all-subsites-and-lists/)

```
#Get all subsites for site collection
$web = $site.AllWebs

#Loop through each subsite and write permissions

foreach ($web in $web)
{
if (($web.permissions -ne $null) -and ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True"))
{
Write-Output "****************************************"
Write-Output "Displaying site permissions for: $web"
$web.permissions | fl member, basepermissions
}
elseif ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -ne "True")
{
Write-Output "****************************************"
Write-Output "Displaying site permissions for: $web"
"$web inherits permissions from $site"
}

#Loop through each list in each subsite and get permissions

foreach ($list in $web.lists)
{
$unique = $list.hasuniqueroleassignments
if (($list.permissions -ne $null) -and ($unique -eq "True"))
{
Write-Output "****************************************"
Write-Output "Displaying Lists permissions for: $web \ $list"
$list.permissions | fl member, basepermissions
}
elseif ($unique -ne "True") {
Write-Output "$web \ $list inherits permissions from $web"
}
}
}
Write-Host "Finished."
$site.dispose()
$web.dispose()
$unique.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below did the job for me with more details.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permissions-f42ea9db